# Non-greedy matching

Tags: regex

In Geany, I want to match the titles of books. One example:

> - Michael Lewis, Liar's Poker, Hodder & Stoughton Ltd, London, 1989

I try to do so with this regex code:

```
,\s.*?,
```

This regex matches too much. it matches: [, Liar's Poker,] and [,London,].
I want to have a regex that only matches the title.

Comment: How is title denoted? Maybe position (after specific number of commas) in string?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Replace `Liar's Poker` with some text?

Comment: If you need to somehow match that, it will be rather troublesome with no more details. Try something like [`(?<=,\s)[^,\r\n]+(?=(?:,[^,\r\n]*){3}$)`](https://regex101.com/r/o62Ldm/2/).

Comment: Is there a possibility of a comma inside a title (or any of the other fields)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this regex with no global modifier. If you set global modifier i.e. g then it will return further matches like you have experienced.

```
,\s*([^,]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DixiMu/1/)

As you want to ignore further matches thus you may try this too:

```
^.*?,\s*([^,]+).*$
```

You will get **Liar's Poker** in group 1

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/DixiMu/2/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 /(, \w+[']?\w? \w+,)/g
```

this regex will get you this

```
[", Liar's Poker,"]
```

you will have to do additional processing to remove those leading and trailing commas. Try it out and see if this works for you.